# How many values within a range have a base-256 representation that contains all the digits in a set?

Tags: sequences-and-series, big-numbers

A hobbyist programmer enquires...

** Situation: **

- An iterator iterates over a range of big-numbers from 'min' to  'max'.
- The current iteration's value is represented by a fixed-length array of 65535 values in the range of 0-255. (i.e. The array is always a 65535-digit base-256 number, with leading zeroes if required.)

**Problem**:

- I want to include only the 'valid' values in the range, and skip over invalid values.
- A value is valid if its base-256 representation contains at least one instance of every value in a given set of 'required values'.
- a 'required value' is a value from 0-255
- the size of the set of required values is a power of 2, from 1-256

**Question**:

How can I determine up-front the total number of valid values contained within a range?

**(Less-pressing) question:**

Is there an elegant way of iterating over only the valid values, skipping value I know will be invalid?

Currently, I have to run through the array checking for the each required value at every iteration, and incrementing and re-checking if it's invalid.

But that method is no help in finding the total number of valid values, as the iteration position may be incremented by (rather large) arbitrary values, and the size of the range is far too large to check every value in it in this manner.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I don't understand one thing that if a required value is in $[0,255]$, then why the size of the set required values is a power of $2$ in $[1,256]$?

Comment: I haven't read the answer below yet, but quickly... the size of the set is unrelated to the range of the values it contains.  I'm testing for the existence somewhere of every colorIndex [256 possible color indices] in different palettes which containing either 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 or 256 different colors

Comment: EDIT: I haven't read the answer below yet, but quickly... the size of the set is unrelated to the range of the values it contains.  I'm testing for the existence in an image of each color index [0, 255] defined in different palettes containing either 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 or 256 different color incides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with a simplification, setting $\min=0, \max=256^{65535}-1$, which corresponds to taking all arrays of the sort you describe.  You can compute how many have a particular set of $k$ values somewhere using the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  There are $256^{65535}$ total strings.  There are $255^{65535}$ strings missing a particular value, because all the values have to come from the remaining $255$ choices.  That would leave us with $256^{65535}-k255^{65535}$ that have all the $k$ values represented, except that we have subtracted twice the ones that are missing two different values, so we have to add them back in.  For two specific values, there are $254^{655435}$ strings and there are $k \choose 2$ pairs of values to be missing, so we add in ${k \choose 2}254^{65535}$  We keep going, getting finally $$\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i{k \choose i}(256-i)^{65535}$$

To deal with $\min$ or $\max$ not being at the limit, we only need to deal with $\max$ being smaller.  For higher $\min$, we can do the calculation over $[0,\max]$ and $[0,\min-1]$ and subtract.  I would write a recursive function, which I will describe by example as if your arrays are base $10$ instead of $256$.  Say you wanted numbers up to $456999$ that included $2$ and $7$.  I would say that is the same as three times the numbers $00000-99999$ that include $2$ and $7$ plus those $00000-99999$ that include $7$ plus those $00000-56999$ that include $2$ and $7$.  Basically take off the first digit, figure out what digits are still required, and call the routine with the smaller case.

To iterate over them I can only suggest starting with $\min$, counting by $1$'s and keeping the status updated as you carry.  If you are looking for $2$ and $7$, when you get to $27000$ you know all the numbers will be acceptable for a while.  That may be more bookkeeping than you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and detailed solution!  I'll need some time and a strong coffee) to read the linked information and digest the solution fully before accepting.

Comment: So thanks again. I've had my coffee now, read up as much as I dare on inclusion-exclusion, and I believe I can grok the logic behind your approach.  It also occurred to me that my "dumb" iterator could probably  be optimised enough for purpose if upon finding an invalid value, the missing digits themselves are stuiffed into the value starting from its least-significant place (and taking into account the order of the missing required values, and the existing value thresholds. Hmm maybe not entirely simple, but I suspect clever 'bookkeeping' could end up being *lot* more work that it's worth.